# getting anaconda2 error in installing pip

Tags: python

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Error
>   5] Access is denied:
>   'c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

This is the error which is I am getting when I am trying to install pip. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running the command, you are getting user permissions, not admin permissions. You can try running the terminal as admin, and then using the same command, it will work.

Otherwise, as it says, you can add `--user` to the end of the command, it will run it without trying to reach "admin-only" directories.